# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty E\{X_n^2\} \lt \infty$ then $\dfrac{S_n}{n}\to 0$ almost everywhere.

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ be independent random variables with mean zero and finite variance. Put $S_n= X_1+\cdots+X_n$. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty E\{X_n^2\} \lt \infty$ then $\dfrac{S_n}{n}\to 0$ almost everywhere.

---

I have a intution that Kronecker's lemma will be helpful but don't know how to proceed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Denote by $\gamma$ the sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathsf E(X_i^2)<\infty$. Note that independence implies 
$$\mathsf E(X_iX_j)=\mathsf EX_i\cdot\mathsf EX_j=0,~i\not=j$$
Hence
\begin{align}\mathsf E\left(\frac {S_n}n\right)^2&=\frac 1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf EX_i^2+\frac 2{n^2}\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}\mathsf E(X_iX_j)\\
&=\frac 1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf EX_i^2\le\frac{\gamma}{n^2}
\end{align}
and by Chebyshev's inequality we have 
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}\left(\left|\frac{S_n}n\right|\ge\varepsilon\right)\le\frac{\mathsf E(S_n/n)^2}{\varepsilon^2}\le\frac{\gamma}{n^2\varepsilon^2}
\end{align}
Now invoke Borel-Cantelli lemma to get the result.